# How can I make this search faster in python?

Tags: python, performance, search, int

I'm searching for a value from one file in the lines of another. The exact value will only occur once in the search file. How can I make this process faster? Here is my current code:

```
filltaxlist = open("file with query number.txt", "rw")
fulltaxa = open("output file with hit line match", "rw")

for line in filltaxalist:
    line = line.strip()
    taxid = re.split("\t", line)
    lookup = taxid[5] # this value is a number and I need the exact match only so I convert it to an integer
    int1 = int(lookup)
    for line in open("File to search.txt", "r"):
        data = re.split(',', line)
        hit = int(data[0]) # every value in this file is a number separated by a ,
        if lookup in line:
            if int1 == hit:
                fulltaxa.write(line)
```

This works fine as it is written just very slow. Also the file that I am searching in is over a GB in size. The

Example of `filltaxlist` line:

```
cvvel_1234    403454663    29.43    3e-30    55.55555555234    1172189
cvell_1444    2342333      30.00    1e-50    34.34584359345    5911
cvell_1444    234230055    23.23    1e-60    32.23445983454    46245
cvell_1444    233493003    23.44    1e-43    35.23595604593    46245
```

What `fulltaxa` should return:

```
1172189, 5943, 1002030, 12345
5911, 11234, 112356, 234, 3456, 44568, 78356
46245, 123, 3432456, 123488976, 23564, 334
46245, 123, 3432456, 123488976, 23564, 334
```

Comment: You read through the file once for every line in `filltaxalist`.

Comment: `if int == hit` should be `if int1 == hit` I suppose.

Comment: Is `filltaxlist` very large?

Comment: filltaxlist will be ~10-30 thousand lines

Comment: You're basically trying to do a table join without a real database. If you have enough memory to put the data from `filltaxlist` into a list (or better yet, a dictionary of some kind with taxid as key), then do that. Otherwise, you might investigate putting all this info into a real datanase.

Comment: `re.split` is unnecessary here, you could use `line.rpartition("\t")[2]` and `line.partition(",")[0]` correspondingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use a database

As others have mentioned, the easiest approach is probably going to be dumping this into a db (e.g. sqllite). You can use python bindings if you need to interface with the language.

## Pure Python Solution

You read `fulltaxa` entirely for each entry in `filltaxlist` (due to the order of the nesting), it will be more efficient to cache all your queries first, then read `fulltaxa` once only, then sort the output to regain the order of `fulltaxa`.

As the order of the queries is import, we should use a FIFO structure - a [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) will do nicely in our case.

```
from collections import defaultdict
filltaxlist = open("file with query number.txt", "rw")
fulltaxa = open("output file with hit line match", "rw")

possibles = {}
for i, line in enumerate(filltaxalist):
    line = line.strip()
    taxid = re.split("\t", line)
    lookup = taxid[5] # this value is a number and I need the exact match only so I covert it to an integer
    int1 = int(lookup)
    possibles[int1] = i

output_lines = defaultdict(list)
for line in open("File to search.txt", "r"):
    data = re.split(',', line)
    hit = int(data[0]) # every value in this file is a number separated by a ,
    if hit in possibles:
        output_lines[possibles[hit]].append(line)

fulltaxa.writelines(line for lines in output_lines.values() for line in lines)
```

When you run out of queries the above code will throw an IndexError

Some other minor improvements.

```
data = re.split(',', line)
```

is probably slower than

```
data = line.split(',')
```

but you should profile to ensure that this is meaninfgul in your case.

Comment: Thank you for this. Will a set only collect unique values? I was originally reading this into a list but there are duplicate values in filltaxalist that must still be searched.

Comment: set will only collect unique values, switch it out for a [counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) if you need to know the number of instances of each value (e.g. if you wanted to search for the first 3 instaneces if there were 3 duplicates in the query list).

Comment: For this process to work properly the order of occurrence, weather duplicate or unique value, is extremely important which is why I'm going line by line. Line 1 in filltaxlist must match line 1 in fulltaxa. I'll add an example of each file to the question for clarity.

Comment: Correct that is why I'm having an issue with this answer. The order of "file to search.txt" is numerical on data[0].

Comment: It it just the output that you want in the order of the queries in `filltaxlist`?

Comment: @cmh Where is the deque in the new code? The dict do not store duplicate values and I am not getting a FIFO result from the updated code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31463/discussion-between-ian-informatics-and-cmh)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is O(m * n). It's possible to make an O(m + n) algorithm instead by using a dictionary. Even if m is small, it's probably a significant improvement in Python, where the constant factor of dictionary access is not that much different from any other statement.

```
filltaxalist = open("file with query number.txt", "rw")
fulltaxa = open("output file with hit line match", "rw")

filltaxadict = {}
for i, line in enumerate(filltaxalist):
    line = line.strip()
    taxid = re.split("\t", line)
    lookup = taxid[5] # this value is a number and I need the exact match only so I convert it to an integer
    int1 = int(lookup)

    filltaxadict[int1] = i

results = [[]] * len(filltaxadict)
for line in open("File to search.txt", "r"):
    data = re.split(',', line)
    hit = int(data[0]) # every value in this file is a number separated by a ,
    match = filltaxadict.get(hit)
    if match is not None:
        results[match].append(line)

for result in results:
    fulltaxa.writelines(result)
```

This handles duplicates and in the right order; slightly simpler if you don't need to. The file to search can be big; this won't keep its contents in memory, only (a portion of) the contents of filltaxalist, which I assume is not unusually large.